# Unable to do sort in StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

I have a Stateful widget named as a `CategoriesFragment`, which includes a top common action bar and tabs. Each tab consist of sections say Bars, Brunches, Restaurants etc.

Section are having list of data. Now when I am on Section say Bars and I clicked Sort button from top actionbar which is common to all sections I want data to be get sorted accordingly.

I am trying to pass Selected sort option in Bars constructor but how can I rebuild widget?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu can we have a seperate chat, the code is lengthy

Comment: I have solved it using GlobalKey for widget